# presto select column names from another query

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to write a presto query that can assign column names dynamically based on the results of another query but doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('Week', CURRENT_DATE) AS w0,
    DATE_TRUNC('Week', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '7' DAY AS w1
)
SELECT
    100 AS (
        SELECT
            w0
        FROM x
    )
```

Ideally I want to output be like

```
2023-10-23
----------
    100
```

Comment: I don't know any way to have dynamical column names, except by doing a first request and using the result to concatenate in the second query, or reorganizing the result from both queries after the request in your language of choice.. Is it an XY problem? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What if you have several rows? In general Presto AFAIK does not support dynamic pivoting.

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve? do you need data in (say) JSON or XML perhaps?